# wsadmin jython command to retrieve administrative role

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-7, wsadmin

Could you please help me to retrieve the role name of a user using `wsadmin` and `jython` on Websphere 7.

I have already successfully set the role via the command `AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole`.

Answer (score 1):

The method can help you out

**AdminTask.listUserIDsOfAuthorizationGroup()**

```
def listUserIDsOfAuthorizationGroup():
"""list all the users IDs in an AuthorizationGroup

Detailed help for command: listUserIDsOfAuthorizationGroup

Description: list all the users IDs in an AuthorizationGroup

Target object: None

Arguments:
authorizationGroupName - Authorization Group

Steps:
None
"""
#endDef
```

---

**AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole()**

```
def mapUsersToAdminRole():
"""Map userids to one or more admin role in the authorization group.

Detailed help for command: mapUsersToAdminRole

Description: Map userids to one or more admin role in the authorization group.

Target object: None

Arguments:
authorizationGroupName - Authorization Group
*roleName - Name of the role. < administrator | configurator | operator
| deployer | monitor >
*userids - User ID.
accessids - ACCESS IDs. If provided, there should be one for each user id.

Steps:
None
"""
#endDef
```